# Can't make awk loop over file values

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, scripting

*Hi guys*

I'm trying to loop over the values of a file (or multiple files) passed as a parameter to the script as in, `./myscript file1 file2 ...` but `awk` only recognizes the first line of each file.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ ${#} > 0 ]]
do
 for archivo in ${@}
 do
  read url filename <<<$(awk -F',' '{print $1, $2}' $archivo)
  curl -o $filename $url
 done
done
```

Files passed as params to the script have the following structure:

```
url1,filename1
url2,filename2
...
```

The goal is, whenever the script is called with one or more parameters, `awk` should parse (and pass) the urls and filenames contained inside each file to `curl` for it to download the files listed.
Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance and happy day!

Comment: You don't seem to be using awk here for anything more than changing a `,` separator to a whitespace one - why not simply set the shell's `IFS` to `,` and read the 2 fields directly?

Comment: How can I loop over the contents of the file? Should I use `cat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that your loop structure appears to be screwed up (you only read one `url`-`filename` pair for each file), the unquoted command substitution `$(awk -F',' '{print $1, $2}' $archivo)` is going to be subject to word-splitting on the default `IFS`, with the result that the awk output is going to get concatenated onto a single line. Compare:

```
$ echo $(printf 'foo bar\nbaz bam\n')
foo bar baz bam
```

versus

```
$ echo "$(printf 'foo bar\nbaz bam\n')"
foo bar
baz bam
```

However this is really a useless-use-of-awk - you can set the shell's `IFS` to `,` and read your files directly. Probably what you want is:

```
for archivo in "$@"
do
  while IFS=, read -r url filename rest
  do 
    curl -o "$filename" "$url"
  done < "$archivo"
done
```

Comment: Excellent! I don't fully comprehend the use of strong quoting vs soft quoting. Guess I should go back to the bash manual. Thanks!

Comment: @arlugones To learn about quotes in shell please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Much obliged @EdMorton!